# How to define if-else function using dataframe columns as arguments in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to write a function and then apply it for a dataframe's column in pandas.
My dataframe looks like this.Data is sorted by id and then by period columns.

```
        period       id   column1
0    2013-01-31      5   NaT
1    2013-02-28      5   28 days
2    2013-03-31      5   31 days
3    2013-04-30      5   30 days
4    2016-05-31      6   NaT
5    2016-06-30      6   30 days
6    2016-08-31      6   62 days
```

The new column values should be defined according to values in column1:

if column1=NaT or column1>31
then new column eqauls to the value in period column

Else - values of new column should be copied from its previous row: 
new column ith row= new column i-1 row.

I am very new to python and my code doesn't work:

```
def f(x):
    if not x or x > 31
    return x=df['period']
    else
    return x=x.shift()
df['newcolumn'] = df['column1'].apply(f)
```

The output should be this:

```
        period       id   column1  newcolumn
0    2013-01-31      5   NaT       2013-01-31 
1    2013-02-28      5   28 days   2013-01-31 
2    2013-03-31      5   31 days   2013-01-31 
3    2013-04-30      5   30 days   2013-01-31 
4    2016-05-31      6   NaT       2016-05-31
5    2016-06-30      6   30 days   2016-05-31
6    2016-08-31      6   62 days   2016-08-31
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What's the output you get? your syntax is obviously wrong but I'm trying to understand whether you wrote here pseudo-code or the real code you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first it might be necessary to convert period to datetime: using [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

```
df['period']=pd.to_datetime(df['period'])
```

**Then you can Use [Dataframe.where](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) with [DataFrame.ffill](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html):**

```
df['newcolumn']=df['period'].where((df["column1"]>pd.Timedelta("31 days"))|(df["column1"].isnull())).ffill()
print(df)



      period  id  column1 newcolumn
0 2013-01-31   5     NaT  2013-01-31
1 2013-02-28   5 28 days  2013-01-31
2 2013-03-31   5 31 days  2013-01-31
3 2013-04-30   5 30 days  2013-01-31
4 2016-05-31   6     NaT  2016-05-31
5 2016-06-30   6 30 days  2016-05-31
6 2016-08-31   6 62 days  2016-08-31
```

Comment: I'm glad to help!:)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `df.where(cond, other)` which return return df's row if condition match else returns other

```py
df["newcolumn"] = df["period"].where(df["column1"].isnull() | (df["column1"]>pd.TimeDelta("31D")), df["column1"].shift())
```

Comment: Dev, thank you very much. I run your code (just small correction: instead of df["columns1"].shift()) I used df["newcolumn"].shift()) . It gives the following error: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: This is because you are using `or` instead of ` |`.....but this solution is not correct